# How do I run a SQL query only if it has no specific value in it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with an sql query i want to run. Basically I want to update a table only if it has no '.' in it (for example 1 row has value '2' and the other row will have value '2.1', in this case i would only want to update the value with a 2.) This is what I tried

```
UPDATE new__tags SET sort_order = 1 WHERE id = '.$id. ' AND sort_order NOT LIKE "%.%"';
```

Unfortunately this did not work and still updated everything.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: i think, your `sort_order` field is an `int` type, you'll need to cast it to `char` before applying `LIKE` on it

Comment: AND sort_order NOT REGEXP  "[.]"'

Comment: what is the type of sort_order column. it is working if it is 'double' for me.

Comment: Try to accept/upvote helpful answers... otherwise no one will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"UPDATE new__tags SET sort_order = 1 WHERE id = $id AND CAST(sort_order AS CHAR) NOT LIKE '%.%'";
```

Comment: try the edited code, i had to cast the sort_order so mysql can search the column as a character field

Answer (score 0):

If your `sort_order` is an `INT` , use [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html)

```
"UPDATE `new__tags` SET `sort_order` = 1 WHERE `id` = '.$id. ' AND CAST(`sort_order`  as CHAR) NOT LIKE '%.%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i tested with phpmyadmin

```
"UPDATE new__tags SET sort_order = 1 WHERE id = $id AND sort_order NOT REGEXP '[.]'";
```